# Multiple domains on the same WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect, dns

I have a Wordpress site runing on Apache and now I want to add another domain adress to this site.
In a few words here... I have two domain names `domain1.com` and `domain2.com` .
`domain1.com` is set and the website is working as it should but now I want to add another domain for the same site. `domain2.com`, must be redirect to `domain1.com`, the problem is that I have no idea why it doesn't work, because when I try to access domain2.com it open the following address.

```
http://domain1.com/wp-signup.php?new=domain2.com
```

Basically this is a redirect to default domain on signup page. What should I do to fix this?
Hope you understood the question, I don't know how to explain it better.

Edit:
I've added the following rules in `.htaccess` and restarted apache, but the problem persists. Maybe is something from Wordpress?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)domain2.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, looks like all this is wordpress related and apache(htaccess) have nothing to do here. The solution that works for me:
I've added this line in wp-config.php and now it works great. Now if I access `domain2.com` it is redirected to `domain1.com`, exactly what I wanted. :)

```
define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://domain1.com' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for my 301 redirects:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com$ [OR]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain2.com$

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\://www.domain1.net/$1" [R=301,L]`

This redirects the domain whether or not people type in the www. part of the url. The backslashes (\) escape the punctuation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this doesn't work. I have no idea why. P.S: I've edited OP, there was a typo in code.